# Using xcopy in VBS (With a Twist)

Tags: vbscript, xcopy, folderbrowserdialog

Okay, so here's the deal: I'm trying to put together a script that will perform a simple xcopy. The problem is I want the users to be able to browse for the source and destination folders. I've got a couple simple parts, but I've been unable to piece them together, especially trying to differentiate the source from destination, and trying to get the output from the browse function...

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Example", 1, "c:\Programs")

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Example", 1, "c:\Programs")

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "Xcopy ""objShell"" ""objShell"" /C /D /E /H /I /K /R /S /Y"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this it will work, tested on Windows 7

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
root = "c:\"
Set source = get_path(objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Source folder", 1, root))
Set target = get_path(objShell.BrowseForFolder(0, "Target folder", 1, root))
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
command = "Xcopy """&source&""" """&target&""" /C /D /E /H /I /K /R /S /Y"
'wscript.echo command
objShell.Run command

function get_path(foldername)
  Set oFolderItem = foldername.Items.Item
  Set selected = oFso.GetFolder(oFolderItem.Path)
  If selected.IsRootFolder Then
    Set get_path = oFso.GetDrive(selected.Drive)
  Else
    Set get_path = oFso.GetFolder(oFolderItem.Path)
  End If
end function
```